# Event / callback for when a user logs in with Meteor + React?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Im using Meteor and React. I need to redirect a user when they log in. Is there an event or callback for this?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './LogInPage.less';

class LogIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: false,
            loggedIn: Meteor.userId() ? true : false,
        };

        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

    login = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.email.value, this.password.value, err => {
            if (err) {
                this.setState({ error: err.reason });
            }
        });
        // if (Meteor.userId()) this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
    };

    render() {
        // if (Meteor.userId()) return <Redirect to="/" />;
        return (
            <div className="LogIn">
                <form onSubmit={this.login}>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" ref={input => (this.email = 

                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" ref={input => (this.password = input)} />

                        <button className="btn" type="submit">
                            Log in
                        </button>

                    {this.state.error && (
                        <p className="form-std__msg form-std__msg--err">
                            {this.state.error}
                        </p>
                    )}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LogInPage;
```

Comment: If loginwithpasswort has no err passed to the callback it can be assumed as successful. At this point you can redirect using your router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no error then you can check using Meteor.user()

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './LogInPage.less';

class LogIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: false,
            loggedIn: Meteor.userId() ? true : false,
        };

        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

    login = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.email.value, this.password.value, err => {
            if (err) {
                this.setState({ error: err.reason });
            } else {
               this.setState({ loggedIn: Meteor.user() ? true : false })
             }
        });
        // if (Meteor.userId()) this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.loggedIn) return <Redirect to="/" />;
        return (
            <div className="LogIn">
                <form onSubmit={this.login}>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" ref={input => (this.email = input)} /> 

                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" ref={input => (this.password = input)} />

                        <button className="btn" type="submit">
                            Log in
                        </button>

                    {this.state.error && (
                        <p className="form-std__msg form-std__msg--err">
                            {this.state.error}
                        </p>
                    )}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LogInPage;
```